# How to enable features in apex oracle application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created an app in apex oracle and forgot to enable access control feature while creating the app. How can I enable it now?
I'm a rookie. Thank You.

Comment: You can always secure an app after you create it. I assume you have authentication figured out. Can you tell us more about your authorization needs? Are their different roles? How do you identify someone's role? Maybe start by reading this: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to You can skip to The Authentication Scheme if authentication is covered.

Comment: As I've said, I'm a rookie. I just want to enable features of my created app.
Thanks, Dan Mcghan :)

Comment: Create a new page. Select "Feature" as the Page Type at the top, then select Access Control. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As you already created your application, you can now create the Access Control page by using the Create Page wizard. Perform the following steps:
1.On the Workspace home page, click App Builder.
2.Select your application.
3.The Application home page appears.
  Click the Create Page button.
4. For Page Type, select Feature and then click Access Control
5. On the Create Access Control:
   * Administration Page Number - Enter an unused starting page number. This
     wizard creates multiple pages starting with the number specified.
   * Administration Page Preference - Specify the administration page to which
     this access control list will be added. (Here, you can either create a new
     page or identify an existing page). Select Create a New Page and click Next.
6. You now see a summary page which lists the multiple pages that will be created.
   Click Create.

What appears next depends upon your selection. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Click Next.
A summary page appears.
Click Create.